# How to select specific fields from main table in Laravel when selecting with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to select specific fields from relationships like so:

```
return Product::whereIn('id', $product_ids)
          ->with([
            'variations' => function($query) {
              $query->select('product_id', 'id', 'variation_name', 'variation_value', 'variation_price', 'variation_qty');
            },
            'customizations' => function($query) {
              $query->select('product_id', 'id', 'group_id', 'customization_price', 'customization_qty');
            }
          ])
          ->get();
```

That works, and that's all I find in the internet. Not how to select specific fields from the main table. I tried the following but none of them worked:

```
->get(['price', 'qty', 'variations', 'customizations']);

Product::select('price', 'qty', 'variations', 'customizations');

->select('price', 'qty', 'variations', 'customizations');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with this `Product::select(['price', 'qty'])`  select with array of columns

Comment: can you show the full code of your query? when you have 2 table together, then you need to mention the table name if both table column names are same, like `->select('products.price', 'products.qty', 'products.variations', 'products.customizations');`